# Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `RTCVideoView` must be a function (received `undefined`)

Tags: ios, react-native, webrtc, react-native-ios, videocall

I am trying to use [react-native-web-rtc](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc) in project.
I have done all the setup for ios and i am getting this error

```
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `RTCVideoView` must be a function (received `undefined`).

This error is located at:
    in RTCVideoView (at SomeView.react.tsx:96)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
```

This is similar to one with [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient) library [issue](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/538)

```
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component BVLinearGradient must be a function (received undefined)

This error is located at:
    in BVLinearGradient (at react-native-linear-gradient/index.ios.js:54)
    in LinearGradient (at SomeView.react.tsx:90)
```

i have tried  bunch of stuff like

- `pod install`
- `npx pod-install`
- `react-native link  react-native-linear-gradient`
- clear watchman cache, clear pod cache

this issue still persist, i think library is not able to identify nativeModule,

Haven't tried this with android, this issue is when working with  ios.